# loading XML file via PHP using simplexml_load_file() - Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, xml

I'm new in XML, I have the following problem. 
My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees>
    <employee>

        <Name>John</Name>
        <Surname>K</Surname>
        <ID>234</ID>
        <e-mail>something@k.com</e-mail>

    </employee>
</employees>
</xml>
```

I'm trying to load the XML file via php:

```
<?php

    $filename='../DBfiles/employeesDB.xml';
    $xml=simplexml_load_file($filename);
?>
```

and I'm getting the following:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ../DBfiles/employeesDB.xml:12: parser error : Extra content 
at the end of the document in C:\path_to_my_file\www\phpAndAjax\add.php on line 4

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): &lt;/xml&gt; in C:\path_to_my_file\www\phpAndAjax\add.php on 
line 4

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in C:\path_to_my_file\www\phpAndAjax\add.php on line 4
```

Comment: You aren't opening `<xml>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
</xml>
```

from the end of file. There is no opening tag `<xml>`, there is a declaration of format which does not require closing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to close the file, just remove the xml closing tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <employees>
  <employee>

    <Name>John</Name>
    <Surname>K</Surname>
    <ID>234</ID>
    <e-mail>something@k.com</e-mail>

 </employee>
</employees>
```